# How to stop error when clicking index greater than 0 in datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to open a form when I click a row in a datagridview and populate the textboxes within the new form. I am able to click the first row (index zero) and it does what I am trying to achieve. But if I click any other row, I get an error:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
private void dataGridViewActivityHire_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        EditFormHire form2 = new EditFormHire();
        var table = dataGridViewActivityHire;

        string name = table.SelectedRows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        string type = table.SelectedRows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        string cost = table.SelectedRows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(table.SelectedRows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value);
        DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(table.SelectedRows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value);

        form2.CustomerName = name;
        form2.Registration = textBoxRegistration.Text;
        form2.ActivityType = type;
        form2.DailyHireCost = textBoxDailyHireCost.Text;
        form2.Total = cost;
        form2.StartDate = start;
        form2.EndDate = end;
        form2.ShowDialog();
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
    }
}
```

I find it odd that I can click the first index and it works correctly, but any index > 0 returns that error. Anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: What is the value of `e.RowIndex` when it goes wrong? On which line is the exception thrown? Run it under the debugger and check the stack trace.

Comment: if the e.RowIndex => 1

Comment: So index 0, which is the first row works fine

Comment: `e.RowIndex` is not directly related to `SelectedRows` in any way.

Comment: You are reading from `SelectedRows`. Is only the first row selected?

Comment: You probably just want to use `Rows`, not `SelectedRows`.

Comment: I just realised how dumb I am. You are correct. I should be using Rows, not SelectedRows